# Does github automatically merges the PR to the parent branch also?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I never faced any issue in git and github regarding the PR. Today a very strange thing happened.

There were 3 branches. `Master, Beta_A and Beta_B.`

Both `Beta_A` and `Beta_B` were made out of `Master` and they use to give PR to `Master` only. Today for one occasion I pulled the `Beta_B` branch for some early code. I merged `Beta_B` branch to my `Beta_A` branch. After some additional change I raised the PR to `Master` from my `Beta_A` branch.

After merging the PR to `Master`, one additional commit was made which merged `Master` into `Beta_B` branch. I have never noticed anything happening like this.

Any specific reasons why did this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request) mentions that

> Pull requests are merged using [the `--no-ff` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge), except for pull requests with squashed or rebased commits, which are merged using the fast-forward option.

Since `B` was merged in `A`, GitHub consider that `B` PR has in effect been merged to `master` (through `A` PR being merged to master): it marks that PR (B) completion with a `no-ff` merge commit.

Comment: But why does a commit was raised which merged `master` into `B`.